# Parsing two rows of CSV data in Android?

Tags: android, parsing, csv

So I am relatively new to Android and I am trying to parse a web based CSV document and use two of the values from this document in my app. I have already successfully parsed a CSV document but it only had 1 row.
The document I am trying to parse looks like this:

```
Light,2012-08-20T11:04:42.407301Z,107
Temperature,2012-08-20T11:04:42.407301Z,24
```

I am trying to get the "107" and the "24" values. Can anyone explain how to do this?
This is the code for my current CSV parser class which can successfully parse one line of CSV data.

```
public class CSVParser {
    static InputStream is = null;
    private String value;

    public String getCSV(String url) {
        // Making HTTP request
        try {
            // defaultHttpClient
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();           

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        try {
            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                String[] RowData = line.split(",");
                value = RowData[2];
                // do something with "data" and "value"
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            // handle exception
        } finally {
            try {
                is.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // handle exception
            }
        }
        return value;
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't get the question. What you are doing seems correct... you are reading 1 line at a time so it should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see you are assigning value = rowData[2], which looks like on the 2 row csv you are only returning the 24 as you assign value each time you read a line. Ie first time it's assigned 107, then on the next readLine it is overwritten with 24.

You should make the value variable an array (if you know number of items to get) or list that can hold multiple strings. Then you add to this array or list in each readLine loop.

So first time it would be (if using value as a `List<string>`)

```
  while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    string[] RowData = line.split(",");
    value.add(RowData[2]);
  }
```

First time round it will add 107 to the list, then next line it will add 24.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I dont have enough space to fit all the new code so i'll just explain what i've done. First off i changed `public String getCSV(String url)` to `public List <String> getCSV(String url)` and i also declared a `private List <String> value` then i implemented the code you suggested and added a return statement for the list value. But now im facing a problem. I have another class called TempLight which is basically used to display these values from the CSV. In this class i declared a `List <String> values` then `CSVParser CSV = new CSVParser();values = CSV.getCSV(CsvURL);`

Comment: Then i did `String light = values.get(0); String temp = values.get(1);` and then set them as text for two different textviews but when i run the program it just crashes. Do you have any idea why this may be? I have enabled the internet permission in the manifest xml and i have parsed CSV data before..

Comment: You'll need to post any error data (ie exceptions text)  or otherwise it's just speculation.

Comment: i think it's saying that it's a `null pointer exception` any idea on how to fix this?

Comment: That means that something is not returning an object ie is null. If you are using eclipse is should pause on the exception. It will tell you in the exception code which is the null variable, on which line of code. It will be near the top of the exception text.

Comment: For some reason LogCat isnt giving me any information on where the error occurs. Is there any other way?

Comment: `08-21 12:10:58.999: E/AndroidRuntime(222): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.helloworld.varun/com.helloworld.varun.TempLightActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException`

Comment: Not sure what that is - its having trouble actually starting the android application. Nothing to do with the code above I don't think.

Comment: well basically my app has a 3 tab layout and each tab launches a different activity and sets the content view to a unique layout xml. The app launches fine and starts up on the default graphs activity, then when i try to load the templight activity (above) it gives an error message in the emulator saying that the app was forced to close.

Comment: Cant tell what is wrong from the little bit of the error above, sorry! Apparantly one of your objects = null which means it hasn't been instantiated or assigned.

Comment: I fixed it! Turns out the problem was exactly what you said it was! I didn't instantiate the list properly, I had done `List <String> value = null;` when instead it should have been `List <String> value = new ArrayList <String>();` Thanks for all the help!

Comment: No problem. If that was the answer could you please click the tick to selct as the answer :)

Answer (score 1):

You have the right idea - so in your idea the while loop run once for each row in the stream until you run out of rows (readline returns null)

Then a single row is split up into multiple strings using split. In your case split should return a array of three (three comma separated elements in the list)

- RowData[0] will contain the text descripition (eg Light)
- RowData[1]  will contain the timestamp
- RowData[2] will contain the number you want

If you want a integer you might want to do something like Integer.Parse(RowData[2])